# Question about getting data from another table

Tags: qliksense

I recently got an opportunity for a job interview but first I need to finish a test project using Qlik. It's my first time using Qlik, I've used SQL before though so I'm somewhat familiar with DBM languages.

The Problem: I have data loaded from two distinct files, Sales and Employee. I want to load data from one file into the other but cannot remember the command to do so. Within the employee file there is data for EmployeeID and EployeeName. I want to load EmployeeName into my sales data where the EmployeeID matches the employeeID In the Sales table. Any suggestions?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can `join` both tables using the `EmployeeID` as key. Qlik will automatically join on fields with the exact same name. And that's the reason for renaming the `employeeID` field in `Sales` table - to match the field name from `Employee` table. Also we are loading only 2 fields from the `Employee` table - ID (used as key) and Name (to bring this field in `Sales` table)

```
Sales:
Load
  employeeID as EmployeeID,
  Some_Sales_Field_1,
  Some_Sales_Field_1,
  Some_Sales_Field_1
From
  Sales.csv
  (txt, utf8, no labels, delimiter is ' ', msq)
;

left join (Sales)

Load
  EmployeeID,
  EmployeeName
From
  Employee.csv
  (txt, utf8, no labels, delimiter is ' ', msq)
;
```